# Why is React useState dependency empty in callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The dependency used in the `useCallback` is coming as `null` even though it is populated when calling it outside of the useCallback. I even tried removing the useCallback and used the `data` variable inside a regular function. It is still null. Any idea why this is happening?

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => { //on page load
  const data = fetchData();
  setData(data)
}, []);

const func = useCallback(async (payload) => {
    console.debug(data); //null
    if (data) //call api with payload
}, [data]);

console.debug(data); //correct population of data

return <MyComponent onSubmit={func} /> //passed to and called from second child down from here
```

Comment: is `data = fetchData()` an async function?

Comment: A great example of fetch her (by hooks or class component): https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: yes. this is just a quick demo of where the data is coming from. the correct data exists every time the page refreshes. it's just not available when used in func()

Comment: so this is working when everything happens in the same component. But when i pass the function to a child Modal and call it from there, it calls `func()` with no problem. But `data` is not available to `func()` at that moment. i see a number of Hooks errors about forwardRefs, but i don't really understand why/how those are used (even with docs) or whether that makes a difference here.

I also tried passing `data` down to the child modal and then passing it back up to `func(payload, data)` directly to see if it would capture it that way. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

1. Pass the data as a parameter in useState to the function.Never mind i don't have data.So i used 'abc'.

   ```
   useEffect(() => { //on page load
    const data = 'abc';
    setData(data)
    func(data)
     }, []);
   ```
2. Next step take the data as a parameter in function.

   ```
    const func = (data) => {
        console.log(data); //now it will have abc
    };
   ```

Comment: yes, this is essentially what I did. but I moved the main part of the `func()` to the child component with a property to allow additional callbacks from the parent

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work in all cases was to move `func()` down to the child...where it's used. And because `data` is used in both parent and children, I passed it down to the children and pushed any modifications to it back up to the parent after running `func()` so the modified `data` could be `set()` in the parent.